# Count the number of orders

Tags: mysql

I have a table (Table1) with the columns `order_item_id` `customer_id` and `order_id` in which I want to count the number of orders per customer. Unfortunately an order with more than one article has the same `order_id`

```
|order_item_id|order_id|customer_id|
|     2       |   30   |    1      | 
|     3       |   30   |    1      | 
|     4       |   42   |    1      | 
|     5       |   33   |    2      | 
|     11      |   32   |    3      | 
|     12      |   33   |    2      | 
|     13      |   33   |    2      | 
|     19      |   69   |    3      |
```

Expected Outcome:

```
|numberOfOrders|customer_id|
|     2        |    1      | 
|     1        |    2      | 
|     2        |    3      |
```

I tried this (and many more):

```
CREATE TABLE X AS
   SELECT 
       customer_id, 
       COUNT(order_id) AS `numberOfOrders`
   FROM Table1 T1 
   GROUP BY customer_id;
```

The problem is, that with this solution it counts every article not the number of orders: so the number of orders for customer 1 is 3 (not 2), for customer 2 is 3 (not 1)....

How can I solve this for a big database with Mysql query?

Answer (score 5):

Try the following solution to `SELECT` your data as expected:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) AS numberOfOrders, customer_id 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY customer_id
```

**Demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee8f62/1/0

Comment: bravo !! optimized answer rather than 2 groups

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to do `GROUP` twice. First `GROUP` for the number of items per order, wrapped by a second `GROUP` for the number of orders per customer:

```
/* second group */
SELECT customer_id
     , count(*)       AS number_of_orders
  FROM ( 
         /* first group */
         SELECT order_id
              , customer_id
              , count(*)         AS order_item_count
           FROM Table1 
          GROUP BY order_id, customer_id  
       ) a
 GROUP BY customer_id
```